# How use genererics in interface

Tags: go, generics, interface

How can I implement a general interface with generics

e.g. I try it

```golang
type input interface {
    models.InputUser | models.InputAdmin
}

type output interface {
    models.OutputUser | models.OutputAdmin
}

type useCase[i input, o output] interface {
    Create(i) error
    Get() o
    Update(i) error
}


type User interface {
    useCase
}

type Admin interface {
    useCase
    GetAll() models.OutputAdmin
    Delete(models.InputAdmin) error
}
```

but got it

> cannot use generic type useCase[i input, o output] without instantiation

Comment: ["Instantiation"](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Instantiations) of a *generic type* means that you explicitly provide the **type arguments** to substitute the **type parameters** of the generic type. E.g., `useCase[models.InputUser, models.OutputUser]`. See [this example](https://go.dev/play/p/T-aTZ3AWzyb), it compiles just fine.